# kendo Angular add Class to ng-template

Tags: javascript, css, angular, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid in Angular, the Grid has some Detailgrid and within I have a GridCellTemplate. I want to add a css class to the ng-template to colorize based on value. But I cannot add.

I tried to add this line to it but giving me an error (working if I add another div inside the ng-template):

```
class="{{getClass(dataItem,column)}}"
```

This is my ng-template Code

```
<kendo-grid-column 
field="{{column}}" >
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem class="{{getClass(dataItem,column)}}">                    
value 
</ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```